# Render the OS X Wait Cursor (Spinning Beachball of Death)

Tags: macos, core-graphics

I would like to render the "spinning beachball of death" but I am completely unfamiliar with Cocoa or how this is done using CoreGraphics.  Ideally, I would like to do it through bash or AppleScript.

Can someone point me in the right direction?